# Why do we say "try and" [verb] instead of "try to" [verb]? (E.g., "Try and call me tomorrow.")

Tags: etymology, colloquialisms

In written and standard semi-formal (and above) spoken English, one would use "try to":

> Try to be a better person.
>
> Try to get the fishhook out of my thumb, please.
>
> Try to find a pharmacy when you need one.

But in spoken English, we (Americans, at least) usually substitute "try and" for all those cases.

"Try to" makes sense because the "to" begins the construction of an infinitive: "try to be", "try to do", "try to act" and so on. "Try and" on the other hand doesn't seem to make any sense.

I'm curious how the "try and" crept in, and when. It's really tough to Google small words like these, so I'm not finding anything on the Web. Is it a contraction of something like "Try hard, and ..."?

Note: I've seen [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/456/2303) and it is somewhat related but doesn't tell me what I want to know.

**Edit**

Observe how, even on this site, [people tend to gravitate toward the "try and"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/127934/2303) construction.

**Turning it on its head**

Note that you can't make a negative construction with "try and":

> It's raining. Try not to get wet.
>
> It's raining. Try not *and* get wet. [?]

Even adding *do* doesn't help. The following means something different from "try not to get wet."

> It's raining. Don't try and get wet.

Even use of *to* instead of *and* there means something else:

> It's raining. Don't try to get wet.

"Try not to get wet" means try to stay dry. "Don't try to get wet" means avoid actively seeking out a soaking, and implies that a soaking might in fact be what you are looking for.

**MORE**

I just happened to notice a video from an editor for Merriam-Webster on this very topic, so I include the link here:

[Merriam-Webster editor discusses "Try and" vs. "try to"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/video/0061-tryandtryto.html?pid=mw_results).
Unfortunately, as of Sept 5, 2023 this video no longer exists on the M-W site.

Comment: Re “we (Americans, at least)”: we Brits do it too.

Comment: Wouldn't "Try and not get wet" be a negative construction that people use? (I'm quite sure I heard it before.)

Comment: Don't know how probable this is, but in Norwegian, the two words corresponding to "and" and "to" (in this context) sound exactly the same (but are written differently - "og" and "å"). So a common challenge for Norwegian kids is to learn which one to use in which context. Consequently, a common mistake made here in Norway is to write "try and" etc, instead of "try to". So it is a possibility that this is a result of Norwegian influence on the English language - either in medieval times, or more recently with Norwegian immigrants in the US in the 19th century.

Comment: @HenrikBerg, I was just going to say the same thing.  It would be
interesting to see arguments for or against this hypothesis.

Comment: Another situation where the variant with 'and' is disallowed is with a follow-on imperative: 'Find a pharmacy when you need one. At least try to.'  'Attempt and ...' and 'seek and ...' can't be used in place of 'try and ...'. The idiosyncrasy is quite possibly, as some have guessed, ease-of-enunciation related.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'd like to hazard a guess on this one. The construct "try and do such and such" sounds to me very much like a figure of speech called hendiadys. This figure of speech is the use of two words joined by a conjunction to mean just the one word, but mean so emphatically. In fact the name "hendiadys" literally means "one through two."

I believe it was more common in classical languages than in English, but this would surely attest to its ancient origin. Examples might be "shock and awe", "rant and rave", "plain and simple". [Wikipedia gives some other examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hendiadys) and more information.

It does seem uncommon with verbs, but it is certainly not unknown. The Bible is replete with such examples. For example, Jesus told Zacchaeus to "haste and come down from the tree." These were not two actions, but one, meaning specifically hastily come down. A common idiom in Bible English is "He answered and said...", again not one action but two, meaning "he said in answer ...".

I wonder if "try and do such and such" is a remnant of that type of hendiadys. Opinions?

Comment: -1: interesting idea, but I don't think it'll fly

Comment: Very interesting. In the Germanic languages, I believe hendiadys was often used with verbs in the Middle Ages, especially in official documents, as in *the King orders **and** commands that...*. This old usage is quite well known in Dutch too: someone aiming at an archaic effect would now jokingly say things like *he has been killed **and** murdered*. However, I'm not sure whether this is the source of *try and*, because both verbs aren't close in meaning there. I don't know; it could be.

Comment: @Fraser Orr: +1 and thanks for *hendiadys*, a figure of speech I did not know until now (and I thought I knew them all). Also, a Google search turns up 'Fowler says that *try and* ... for *try to* ... is a "true example" of *hendiadys*.' [Wikipedia] I'm not a big fan of Fowler, but this is a solid clue nevertheless.

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure why two people downvoted this. Apologies to @Fraser Orr.

Comment: @Fraser Orr: Reversing my downvote. Apologies for not paying close enough attention the first time I read this. I now think what you're saying is somewhat similar to my own attempt to rationalise why people persist in using the form even though they nearly all 'know' (having been told repeatedly) that it's 'wrong'.

Comment: 'Try to V' is harder on those with false teeth than 'try and V'. // Other verbs do not allow this variant of 'V₁ to V₂': *'attempt and ...' / *'seek and [bring reconciliation]' / ''strive and ...'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth FWIW an expression like "I'll try and be a better person" is pretty common, in speech anyway. I know it doesn't exactly match your construction, but it is worth considering. Again this seems to follow that same pattern of hendiadys. Evidently the "trying" and "being" refer to the same action.

Comment: The fact that 'try and V' only works in the imperative and with auxiliaries ('I tried to be a better person' can't use 'and') argues against the 'single lexeme' slant. Even phase structures ('They go shopping'; 'He sat knitting'; 'Go fishing tomorrow!') which show concomitant 'actions', are far more flexible.

Answer (score 13):

The only issue not covered by [the question OP linked to](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/456/difference-between-try-to-do-and-try-and-do) arises from the mistaken assumption that **try and** is some kind of latter-day corruption of an established 'correct' form **try to**.

But that's probably not how to look at it — most likely **try and** was around all the time, and it may well predate **try to**. I think probably various [language mavens](http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/languagemaventerm.htm) considered the 'grammar' of **try and**, decided it contravened their idea of logic, and succeeded in fooling at least some people into their way of thinking for some of the time.

LATER - Thanks to Peter Shor for this little gem...

*Suspect*: "Try and convict me." *Prosecutor*: "Have it your way. We'll try **and** convict you."

I'd also like to make the grammatic/semantic case for **try and**, since others seem to assume it's just an inexplicable linguistic aberration.

**To try** can mean **to make an effort**, which can be seen as an action *in and of itself*. So you can make an effort *and thereby* achieve the desired result. This doesn't really work if you assume **to try** is a synonym for **to attempt**, because grammatically you need to attempt *something*.

Note that we're assuming the effort *will in fact be successful*, **and** therefore the result *will* follow. In this way of looking at things, **to try and do something** is simply a more 'optimistic' phrasing than **try to**.

Some people may object to **try and**, but have no problem with **make an effort and**. Die-hards may need to go one step further and equate **make an effort** with **give it one's best shot**, or similar. As you move further away from the concept of *attempting* with the possibility of failure, and more towards *making the necessary effort* to achieve something, it seems to me that **and** becomes more and more the more appropriate word.

In short, **try and** can be seen as a somewhat more optimistic way of referring to some endeavour than **try to**. It's the linguistic device *hendiadys* as put forward by Fraser Orr, conflating the effort with the accomplishment.

As Jedi warriors such as myself and Yoda say: **There is no try. There is only do.**

Comment: The [obvious Ngrams search](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=try+and%2Ctry+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) supports this thesis that *try and* is plenty old.  Being a corpus of written sources, Ngrams strongly favours *try to*; but (perhaps surprisingly) it shows it winning ever more strongly in recent years — *try to* has been steadily gaining ground in writing since the 1800’s!

Comment: @PLL: I don't really have an opinion on 'correctness' for this one. I prefer to use **try to** in formal writing - not because I think it's more correct, but because I'm aware that some others may think that. In speech I invariably use **try and**. Partly because it seems to roll off the tongue easier for me, partly because I think when actually vocalised, **try to** sounds a little 'twee'.

Comment: In many of the early 1800's instances of "try and", *try* is used in the sense of *put on trial* or *test*. E.g., "with full power to try and punish ...", "to try and judge him", "fear not to try and taste ..." Looking at the first 100 pre-1800 Google books results, I didn't find a single unambiguous instance of "try and" used for "try to." By 1860, however, "try and" used for "try to" seems quite common.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I glanced briefly at NGrams before posting, eyeballing a few early occurences to guard against being misled for that very reason. I've just done it again, and now realise that I simply misparsed things like **try and examine / determine / exercise / etc.** The modern usage must have arrived a bit later.

Comment: Suspect: "Try and convict me." Prosecutor: "Have it your way. We'll try ***and*** convict you."

Comment: haha. It'd be great to find exactly that in the court annals for 1701! I'm not holding my breath though.

Comment: @PLL: The obvious problem with the NGram approach in this case — and don't think I didn't give it a go — is that there are legitimate uses for "try and" which do not mean "try to": "He will try and he will fail," for example.

Comment: @Peter, @Robusto: ah, thanks — I glanced briefly at the hits, but evidently too briefly.  Good catch.

Comment: @Peter Shor, @Robusto, @PPL: So who's going to find and post up the earliest written usage we can find where *try and* was unambiguously used to mean *try to*, as under discussion?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Catherine Cuthbertson appears to have used *try and* for *try to* several times in her novels; the earliest instance I could find is in 1809, in *Santo Sebastiano:* *... but will you try and walk to my parish with me?*

Comment: @Peter Shor: That particular one might be considered slightly ambiguous, with *try* meaning *make an effort*, and *walk* being a 'supplementary' action as per @Fraser Orr's *hendiadys*. But I have no doubt at all about *..wishes to try and reinstate herself...* which occurs on p121 of the same. Many thanks! I really do feel we've nailed this one!

Comment: **pwned** it, as the younger generation might say.

Comment: Just a footnote ... *Santo Sebastiano* was apparently first published in 1806, the 1809 date in the edition on Google must have been for a later printing.

Comment: So *try and win* is the same as *give it you best shot and win* or as Mar Rojo writes *go out there and win*.  *Win! Win! Win! Win!* (Lucy Van Pelt)

Comment: -1 for making up a meaning that this phrase doesn't have

Comment: @DCShannon: I don't understand. Are you simply saying you disagree with my suggestion that ***try and [verb]*** might imply greater expectation of success than ***try to [verb]**?* Or have I "made up" something else?

Comment: @DCShannon: Wot? And I *haven't* had a lifetime's exposure to English? I'm trying and seeing things from your point of view. (But if I want to remain both truthful *and* "syntactically valid" I guess that'll have to be *trying and/but **not** seeing...* :)

Comment: @DCShannon: I can understand the *downvote* if you disagree with my take here - I just don't see the point of the comment. If you're going to say I'm "clearly incorrect" you ought to back that up with some more authoritative source than just your own opinion that I'm wrong. I said I'd "like to make the grammatic/semantic case for [my argument]", and I think I did set out a rational position above. Okay - so you don't agree. But *why?* The fact that you've spoken English all your life is hardly a meaningful counterargument here.

Comment: @DCShannon: Okay, well this is going nowhere. You disagree with my argument above, so you downvote - fair enough. I just don't see the point of you rattling my cage with an associated comment ping if you're not going to back up your position with an argument that I might reasonably either refute or be convinced by.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, what? You're confused because I left a comment explaining my downvote and don't want to argue about it? Leaving a comment explaining your downvote is common courtesy. That's all.

Comment: @DCShannon: You're not even trying *to* convince me of a counterargument, let alone trying ***and*** convincing me. But as I said, this is going nowhere.

Answer (score 6):

Interestingly, the "try to" stays intact and still makes sense when the sentence is turned into a question or into the past tense. The "try and" will not work in these cases.

> Did you try to be a better person?
>
> I tried to be a better person.

None of these will work with "try and". As Rimmer explained, the "try and" creates two actual verb phrases, whereas the "try to" construct is a single verb phrase.

No idea about when or where the "try and" originates, though.

Comment: "Did you try and succeed?" : "I tried and succeeded". I don't see the problem.

Comment: If you pick your sentences carefully enough, then there won't be a problem or there will be a problem, depending on what the intent is. "Did you try and XXX a better person?" -- "Yes, I tried and XXX a better person!" - What word could replace the XXX in these two examples? That's where  I see the difference. With "try to be" there's no difficulty, but with "try and XXX" you need to use a different verb altogether. It's not a problem, but "try and" and "try to" are not completely interchangeable.

Comment: I take your point that they're not completely interchangeable, but OP is interested in getting some kind of history/rationale for how the 'non-preferred' usage came about. And maybe by implication, why it persists (even among many 'careful speakers' when they're not actually writing) despite being universally reviled as 'ignorant' and 'incorrect'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Did you try and succeed?" means "Did you try and did you succeed?" It doesn't mean "Did you try to succeed?"

Comment: @JuanMendes Actually, that's exactly what it means. That's kind of the point of the whole discussion.

Comment: The fact that one has to conjugate the second verb when using *try and* doesn't mean the expression "doesn't work". It works fine for expansive, informal senses of 'fine'. It just requires that you conjugate the second verb. There's nothing untoward about *Did you try and become a better person? Yes, I tried and became a better person* aside from the initial objections against the entire construction.

Answer (score 3):

This usage of "and" is quite common across the US (although long ago a friend who had lived all her life in Manhattan once told me she had never heard it and it made no sense, which I had trouble believing).

In speech, it is an exact synonym for "try to", and does not at all mean that one is doing two different things (trying and then succeeding) as many posters (and a literal reading) suggest.

Teylyn's point that this construction cannot be used in the past tense or in a question is a good one, in particular for showing that "and" is definitely not being used as a conjunction, but this may need refinement.  In particular, I think it can sound acceptable in a question, as in #6:

```
1.   He said he was gonna try an' fix his bike.
2. * Last I saw, he was tryin' an' fixin' his bike.
3. * Last I saw, he was tryin' an' fix his bike.
4. * I wonder if he tried 'n' fixed his bike?
5. * I wonder if he tried 'n' fix his bike?
6.   Didja try an' fix your bike?
7.   Well, try an' fix it!
8. * If he tries an' fix his bike, it'll only take a minute.
9. * If he tries an' fixes his bike, it'll only take a minute.
(starred ones sound wrong to me)
```

Since the infinitival "to" generally binds to the previous word rather than the following word (e.g. "gonna eat") (defying the latin-based grammar notion that "to" belongs to an indivisible unit, "the infinitive"), it seems that this use of "and" is similarly strongly tied to the verb "try", so "try and" is perhaps best thought of like "gonna" or "wanna".  The inapplicability to third person singular (examples 8 and 9) reinforces the notion that it is a late-stage transformation based on final word form.

I'm not sure, but "try and" might also be semantically restricted as compared with "try to".  "Try and" may imply that the activity of the following verb will be performed, but success is not guaranteed, while "try to" can also be used when the following verb is simply a goal or hope.  On this theory, the following would not be ok (they sounded odd to me at first, but the more I repeat them to myself, the more ok they sound, so I'm not so sure about this anymore).

```
10. • He said he was gonna try an' get a promotion.
11. • He said he was gonna try an' get out early for good behavior.
```

Comment: 10 and 11 sound perfectly natural to me. They're the same as _Try and catch me!_ w.r.t. the issue you raise about them, AFAICT.

Comment: Are there any constructions where try gets put in the 3rd person, and it works?  For example, "I'd suggest you try and sleep" is fine, but both "I'd suggest he tries and sleep" and I'd recommend he tries and sleeps" both seem wrong to me.  I was thinking about whether sleep is the bare infinitive or agrees with the subject, but I can't think or a test phrase in the third person where either case sounds natural.

Answer (score 3):

There's some great answers here, and I just wanted to add that "try and" is **easier to say** than "try to", and this might have played a part in its adoption.  That is, "tryand" flows much more easily off the tongue than "tryto", and when you look at the corrupted/slurred forms of both, "try-n" vs "tryta", you almost get a one-syllable word in the first instance.

So, perhaps the other answers give the initial reason for the change, and this effect helps explain its wide adoption.

Answer (score 1):

How would these be different or similar?

Go out there to win.
Go out there and win.

Try to win.
Try and win.

Comment: *Go out there to win* seems more like a statement of intent, whereas *Go out there and win* seems more like encouragement. Context is the key, though.

Comment: Excellent examples, which I think  illustrate @Fraser Orr's *hendiadys* very succinctly.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't as good or thorough an answer as @FumbleFingers above, but one factor in the prevalence of *try and* in spoken English is that its rhythm of stress flows better. The long /u/ sound of the *to* in *try to* makes it uncomfortable to say, even though it works better semantically. I think that's where the entire construction comes from. Fumble's points about the more optimistic connotation aren't mistaken, but I do think it's a *post hoc* rationalization of something we 'got away with' saying, since it's comprehensible enough to keep the conversation going without trouble.

Answer (score -2):

I strongly favour "try to" where it is synonymous with "attempt to".  I don't think I've ever heard anyone say "attempt and ".

> I am going to try to jump the Grand Canyon on a skateboard.

To my ear it is so much tidier than "try and", and none of my examples below would work with "try and", in my opinion.

*It can be negated:*

> I am going to try not to plunge to my death.

*The present participle can also be used:*

> I am trying to find a ramp long enough.

*Also the perfect and future perfect tenses work:*

> I have tried to jump the Grand Canyon on a skateboard, and soon I will have tried to walk
>   again after two months of reconstructive surgery..

Comment: I don't see how this is an answer. Is this an answer?

Comment: @DCShannon It's an answer in the sense that Mr Jones is of the opinion that *try and* should never be used.  I mostly agree, but it's somewhat off topic since the question was about how people started saying it this way.

Comment: @lly Correct. I did neglect to answer the actual question. Oops! But then again, so did Mar Rojo and Teylyn without criticism. Nice flag, btw :)