# "Don't try and Lance Armstrong your way outta this one!"

Tags: american-english

I don't know in the sentence I will refer to, what does "Lance Armstrong your way"  mean, is there any irony or not? The situation is between a man and a woman, and the man wants to deny a mistake he had made. Her friend had heard a sentence which the man had said, and then the woman says:

> She was in the other room, you bastard! In the next room, ok, so don't try and Lance Armstrong your way outta this one!

Comment: It could just as well be *Don't try and Lenny Bruce your way outta this one.* He said, "In fact, if your old lady walks 
in on you, deny it. Yeah. Just flat out and she'll believe it: "I'm tellin' ya. This chick came downstairs with a sign around her neck `Lay On Top Of Me Or I'll Die'. I didn't know what I was gonna do..."

Comment: You should try concocting **adhoc allegorical idioms** yourself. For example - Don't try a George W Bush on us.
- Please don't try any Bill Clinton maneuver on that intern.
- I am afraid she is going on a Mary Kay Letourneau on one of her students.
- Mum, eating breakfast you make is like chewing on newspaper.
- In presenting yourself as the persona of this company, would you be attempting a Steve Jobs or a Mark Zuckerberg?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common phrase is "Don't lie your way out of this one" or "You can't just think your way out of this one", which mean "Don't lie in order to resolve this situation" and "Just thinking won't resolve this situation" respectively.

The writer verbifies (i.e. using a non-verb as a verb) "Lance Armstrong" to mean "act in such a way that lance armstrong would act." This is pretty ambiguous, but this could be referring to him being accused of taking performance enhancing drugs and him denying it.

Comment: I'm not an avid sports fan - in fact, I've no idea what *particular* sport Lance Armstrong is famous for. But I do know he's famous for ***lying*** about his use of drugs. More specifically, perhaps, he's famous for *being accused of lying*, since I also have no idea whether the accusations are true. Anyway, my point is I seriously doubt anyone would "verbify" his name with any other meaning.

Comment: Armstrong is (or was, as he is banned) a competitive cyclist whose incessant denials of use of performance enhancing drugs went even to the extent of a suit under the favorable English libel law. (The suit was settled with Armstrong receiving 300,000 pounds.) The accusations were, however, true.

Answer (score 9):

I'd interpret this as a newfangled way of saying:

#### "Don't try to *weasel* your way out of this one."

As a verb, to *weasel* means to obtain some sort of personal gain through questionable behavior. Some dictionaries also list *weasel out* as a phrasal verb; [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/weasel-out) defines it as:

> to evade a responsibility, esp. in a despicable manner

As a noun, a [weasel](http://www.wordnik.com/words/weasel) can be a devious or sneaky person.

So, in the wake of the doping scandal, Lance Armstrong is an outed weasel. He denied allegations for several years, but that was found to be all lies. So, substitute "Lance Armstrong" for "weasel," and we've got the quote you presented to us.

I don't think it's an establish idiom yet, but it has some potential.

Comment: I am not sure that weasel is the right word.  He wasn't really sneaky and everyone knew he was lying for a long time.  I would think the term needed would need to reflect the power that he had and the fact that he was using his power to negotiate facts.

Comment: @Tom - I didn't mean it's an exact match, but I do think the O.P. is asking about a variant of the phrase _weasel your way out of_.

Comment: FWIW, I think *to Lance Armstrong* is needed precisely because *weasel* means to Clintonesquely redefine terms or to Blairily change the accusation to a less dangerous one, whereas Armstrong unblushingly faced down his accusers with a Goebbelian Big Lie.