# `Try doing and do` vs `Try doing and doing`

Tags: grammar, verbs

Which one is correct, possibly both?

- Try reducing your query and searching again
- Try reducing your query and search again

Comment: @FumbleFingers no, I don't think it is even close

Comment: I think your "syntactic ambiguity" is essentially the same as [***try and convict me***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27008/why-do-we-say-try-and-verb-instead-of-try-to-verb-e-g-try-and-call#comment46633_27024). Also ***try and open the door*** (because ***to try the door*** can mean ***see if the door can be opened*** all on its own). In practice your examples don't really admit of any *semantic* ambiguity though - it's just a matter of syntax / parsing. (1) - see if reducing the query AND re-searching works, or (2) see if reducing the query works, [if so] THEN re-search.

Comment: I think both of them are acceptable and the difference is miniscule. The first is equivalent to "Try reducing your query and try searching again", the second is equivalent to "Try reducing your query and then search again".