# "Don't try to be a hero" vs "Don't try and be a hero"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

"Don't try **to** be a hero"

"Don't try **and** be a hero"

What's the difference?  They both seem to be common according to Google.

Do they mean exactly the same thing?  Is one more correct than the other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we say "try and" \[verb\] instead of "try to" \[verb\]? (E.g., "Try and call me tomorrow.")](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27008/why-do-we-say-try-and-verb-instead-of-try-to-verb-e-g-try-and-call)

Comment: In many British accents, and I suspect other accents as well, the 'o' in 'to' is often elided so that we say things like "try _t'_ do a good job of that" rather than "try _to_ do a good job of that". This is mainly because pronouncing the 'o' in those circumstances  can be rather awkward. Using 'and' instead of 'to' seems easier to me.