# Elliptical "try and pull" instead of to-infinitive "try to pull"?

Tags: infinitives

> Why does she try and pull the stunt?

This is probably an elliptic sentence - Why does she try the stunt and why does she pull the stunt (off)? - but it still seems like very bad style to me.

> Why does she (even) **try to pull** the stunt (off)?

I am aware that it is not clear that the attempt was successful, however the to-infinitive comes much more naturally to me, for whatever reason. From context, it is clear that it was successful.
So, would you consider it weak style to use an ellipse like this?

Comment: The format is real common in the States. Try and talk me outta it. Come and get it.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate, though I don't know if I agree with the analysis in the answers: [Why do we say "try and" \[verb\] instead of "try to" \[verb\]? (E.g., "Try and call me tomorrow.")](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/27008/191178). For Americans like me, it just sounds natural to use "and" like this.

Comment: I don't see this as a deletion; 'He failed to catch the pike' is certainly not elliptical for ''He failed and he managed to catch the pike', etc. These are catenative structures of the V₁ to V₂ ... (verb + to-infinitive clause) type. Substitution of 'and' for 'to' only works for V₁  = try, as far as I am aware.

Comment: It's not just "try and...". There are some similar constructions such as "come and...", "go and...", and (possibly only dialect) "see and..." (rather than "see that you...").